# Add and display unit price field to WooCommerce product variations

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, price, product-variations

In WooCommerce, for variable products, I want to add a field that shows the price of one unit of the product to the user. For example, I have a product that is priced at $1000 for a pack of 100, but I want to add a field to show the user the price per piece (one unit). Therefore, the price entered for the unit price field should be shown to the user instead of the variation price, but in my code it does not show the price on the product page.

Here is my code:

```php
// Add custom field to product variations
function add_price_per_unit_field_variation($loop, $variation_data, $variation) {
    woocommerce_wp_text_input(array(
        'id'          => '_price_per_unit[' . $variation->ID . ']',
        'label'       => __('Price per unit for Variation ' . $loop, 'woocommerce'),
        'placeholder' => '',
        'desc_tip'    => 'true',
        'description' => __('Enter the price per unit for this variation.', 'woocommerce'),
        'value'       => get_post_meta($variation->ID, '_price_per_unit', true),
    ));
}
add_action('woocommerce_variation_options_pricing', 'add_price_per_unit_field_variation', 10, 3);

// Save custom field for product variations
function save_price_per_unit_field_variation($variation_id, $i) {
    $price_per_unit = $_POST['_price_per_unit'][$variation_id];
    update_post_meta($variation_id, '_price_per_unit', esc_attr($price_per_unit));
}
add_action('woocommerce_save_product_variation', 'save_price_per_unit_field_variation', 10, 2);

// Replace variation price with price per unit on product page
function display_price_per_unit_single($price, $product) {
    if ($product->is_type('variable')) {
        $price_per_unit = get_post_meta($product->get_id(), '_price_per_unit', true);

        if (!empty($price_per_unit)) {
            return wc_price($price_per_unit) . ' per unit';
        }
    }
    return $price;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_variable_sale_price_html', 'display_price_per_unit_single', 10, 2);
add_filter('woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'display_price_per_unit_single', 10, 2);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have completely revised your code using more recent code and hooks, replacing the displayed price on the selected variation, by the price per unit when set:

```php
// Display custom field on product variations options pricing
add_action('woocommerce_variation_options_pricing', 'display_variation_price_per_unit_field', 10, 3);
function display_variation_price_per_unit_field($loop, $variation_data, $variation) {
    $variation_object = wc_get_product($variation->ID);

    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
        'id'            => "_price_per_unit[{$loop}]",
        'label'         => sprintf( __('Price per unit (%s)', 'woocommerce'), get_woocommerce_currency_symbol() ),
        'wrapper_class' => 'form-row form-row-first',
        'placeholder'   => '',
        'desc_tip'      => 'true',
        'description'   => __('Enter the price per unit for this variation.', 'woocommerce'),
        'value'         => wc_format_localized_price( $variation_object->get_meta( '_price_per_unit' ) ),
    ) );
}

// Save custom field value from product variations options pricing
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_process_variation_object', 'save_variation_price_per_unit_value', 20, 2 );
function save_variation_price_per_unit_value( $variation, $i ) {
    $price_per_unit = isset($_POST['_price_per_unit'][$i]) ? wc_clean( wp_unslash($_POST['_price_per_unit'][$i])) : null;
    
    $variation->update_meta_data('_price_per_unit', $price_per_unit);
}

// Display the formatted price per unit on selected variation
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'display_selected_variation_price_per_unit', 10, 3 );
function display_selected_variation_price_per_unit( $variation_data, $product, $variation ) {
    $price_per_unit = $variation->get_meta('_price_per_unit');
    
    if ( $price_per_unit != null ) {
        $price_to_display = wc_get_price_to_display( $variation, array( 'price' => floatval($price_per_unit) ) );
        $variation_data['price_html'] = wc_price( $price_to_display );
    }
    return $variation_data;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

---

**Addition: 


The selected variation price per unit replace the product variation price range.**

You will replace the last function from my previous code with:

```php
// Add the variation formatted price per unit to the form data
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'available_variation_formatted_price_per_unit', 10, 3 );
function available_variation_formatted_price_per_unit( $variation_data, $product, $variation ) {
    $price_per_unit = $variation->get_meta('_price_per_unit');
    
    if ( $price_per_unit != null ) {
        $variation_data['display_price_pu'] = wc_get_price_to_display( $variation, array( 'price' => floatval($price_per_unit) ) );
        $variation_data['price_pu_html']    = wc_price( $variation_data['display_price_pu'] );
    }
    return $variation_data;
}
```

Then you will also add the following code:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_variations_form', 'woocommerce_after_variations_form_js', 10 );
function woocommerce_after_variations_form_js() {
    global $product; ?>
    <script>
    jQuery( function($){
        const originalPrice = $('p.price').html()
        $('form.cart').on('show_variation', function(event, data) {
            if ( data.price_pu_html !== undefined ) {
                $('p.price').html( data.price_pu_html );
            } else {
                $('p.price').html( originalPrice );
            }
        }).on('hide_variation', function(){
            $('p.price').html( originalPrice );
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Tested and works.

[image]

Comment: Thank you and thank you for your good efforts to help me This code is correct but there is a problem Maybe I said it wrong Based on this code, when the product page is opened for the user, the price of the same variable product is shown, not the price of one unit. I want when the user opens the product page must see the price of a unit instead of the variable price and after he selects the variable, the variable price is displayed.

Comment: I'm so sorry if I bother you.

Yes, I want to put a unit price field for each variaton and enter the unit price of the variaton so that the user can see the unit price first on the product page and then see the variaton price when he selects the variable.
For example, I have a variable product called screw. This product has a variable, including a package of 100 pieces with a price of 1000 dollars. By default, when the user enters the product page, the variaton price is displayed for him, but I want to show the price of one unit of the product (screw).

Comment: Thank you for your good explanation...
Is there a way to show the unit price of the product instead of the variations price on the product page other than using javascript?

Comment: I have added an addition in my answer, try it…

Comment: Hi and so many thanks for your update, you are really genius man. I have an question, Is it possible to Modify it functionality to displaying a custom field price initially and then updating the price after the user clicks on a variation? In your code, after selecting the variation, a new price appears that is a variation price. Is it possible to change the same price after selecting the variation and not show another price? 1. Before Select variation: https://ibb.co/SR00ZRC 2. After Select variation: https://ibb.co/sHq6PFY – 
user22774038